# How to find a file that contains the specified string in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, search, grep, unix-shell, strings

I'm searching for the way to find a *file* that contains specified string text.

It should be fast as possible but its not that important.

I was reading the manual, and I've build something like that: `grep my_string * -r` and it works at all, but if there are many directories to search.

Are there any other ways to find a file that contains specified string in FreeBSD?

Comment: there aren't many ways that could make searching for string faster, than grep. and if you want to search multiple directories, just list them ... `grep -r string dir1 dir2 dir3`, or just grep the string on the whole drive `grep -r string /` (this could take a long time though and i'm not sure if freebsd grep will dig into devices by default)

Comment: @Fox FreeBSD will dig into the devices as well, but will most likely spit out a warning and move on.

Comment: The `-x` option will prevent `find` from descending into directories with device numbers different from the starting point of the find, so devices will be skipped.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
grep -rl my_search_pattern    my_dir1 my_dir2 my_dir3 my_another_file
```